# How to keep common name of SSL while changing port wss

Tags: c#, ssl, websocket, ssl-certificate, pfx

I have a problem here. I created a windows app that requires interaction between browser and desktop apps. In the desktop app, I include `WebSocket` Secure made by [Dave]([WebSocket Server in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1063910/WebSocket-Server-in-Csharp)).

I have a valid pfx file. While using the default port (443), everything runs smoothly. The URL shows the CN of the SSL. My window app then has to use other port other than default ones (443), when I change in setting it runs not as per CN  of the SSL but instead `localhost:portnum`. how to make it run using CN in ports other than 443? Please help.

Comment: Port number and host are in this line of code : string handshakeHttpRequest = string.Format(handshakeHttpRequestTemplate, uri.PathAndQuery, uri.Host, uri.Port, secWebSocketKey);

Comment: @jdweng i'd already change the port. the websocket is already open, i can access a html pages inside the project. just the url doesn't showing CN names. say if i use 443 port, it shows abc.abcde.com, if i use other port say 48025, it shows localhost:48025. how can i change localhost:48025 back to abc.abcde.com?

Comment: The server may be redirecting to localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer this.

I have checked the link that you have pasted and came across the following code snippet:

```
private static void Main(string[] args){

IWebSocketLogger logger = new WebSocketLogger();

try
{
    string webRoot = Settings.Default.WebRoot;
    int port = Settings.Default.Port;

    // used to decide what to do with incoming connections
    ServiceFactory serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory(webRoot, logger);

    using (WebServer server = new WebServer(serviceFactory, logger))
    {
        server.Listen(port);
        Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(TestClient));
        clientThread.IsBackground = false;
        clientThread.Start(logger);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.Error(null, ex);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
}
```

Within the try block there is this code line:

```
int port = Settings.Default.Port;
```

Maybe trying setting that to an auto assign port fix your problem.

Comment: i'd remove the Settings class and now as it is a constant value, i hardcoded everything. it's just when i use the default 433, the page is up with the certificate trusted, the url shows abc.abcde.com. when i use my custom port, the certificate is not trusted, and i have lost access to abc.abcde.com. i have to go to localhost:48025. Is there anything that differentiate between default port and other port? Please help me

Comment: So, in order to get this straight, you're certificate does not work on any other port rather than the default one?
Are you getting the error "Your connection is not private", if that is the case take a look at this: https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/what-is-common-name-mismatch-error and this: https://medium.com/@cheapsslcouponcode/how-to-fix-ssl-certificate-name-mismatch-error-5f84842a765

Comment: i think perhaps it's the only way around. never mind i'll use default port then. this problem is too hard to solve/think therefore i'll make it pass. thank you for you time.

Comment: No worries, I am glad that I helped out a bit!